# Php json not returning all rows

Tags: php, json

I´m trying to select all the images from db but it´s not returning me all the rows. What am I doing wrong below?

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM iMoveis";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     array_push(
         $response, 
         array(
             "images"=>$row["img1"], 
             "images"=>$row["img2"], 
             "images"=>$row["img3"], 
             "images"=>$row["img4"], 
             "images"=>$row["img5"]
         )
    );
}

echo json_encode(array("posts"=>$response), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

?>
```

**EDIT**

DB fields

SELECT `imovel_id`, `arquivo`, `state`, `city`, `negocio`, `imovel`, `mobilia`, `garagem`, `preco`, `likes`, `img1`, `img2`, `img3`, `img4`, `img5` FROM `iMoveis` WHERE 1

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post your table structure also.

Comment: @Parixit can´t post images so take a look at my db fields

Comment: Please check my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my php file to output the same key value inside the array "posts", so I could get all the rows

```
$images = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$images[] = array('image' => $row['img1']);
$images[] = array('image' => $row['img2']);
$images[] = array('image' => $row['img3']);
$images[] = array('image' => $row['img4']);
$images[] = array('image' => $row['img5']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $img = array();
   foreach($row as $k=>$each) {
     if(in_array($k, array('img1','img2','img3','img4','img5')) {
        array_push($img, $each);
      }
   }
   $response['images'][] = $img;
}
```

Comment: Also, the pushed array's keys should be unique. The current implementation will only hold the last `images` key

Comment: [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) is returning both assoc and numbered indices, because the default value of parameter `$result_type` is `MYSQLI_BOTH`.

Comment: @mapek I prefer `assoc` when required to get keys. I was not aware. Thanks for pointing.
@madsongr Please re check I changed function name.

Comment: @Parixit yes I did it, but I need the same key to communicate with my json parser on android application. Even with assoc it brings me the same

Comment: @madsongr Please add your DB structure and output which you want